# How to push an item to a nested array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make an api with express.js and mongoDB (using mongoose) and don't know how to properly add an item to my existing array (nextUp). For example I have an existing User in my database with templates: { issues: { nextUp: [], inProgress: [], completed: [] } } and want to add e.g. {issueName: 'MyName', issueDate: '20/5/2020'} to nextUp field.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        minlength: 3,
        sparse: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 255,
        sparse: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 8,
        sparse: true,
    },
    newsletterSubscribed: {
        type: Boolean,
    },

    termsAndPolicyAgreement: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
    },
    templates: {
        title: {
            type: String,
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
        },
        issues: {
            nextUp: [
                {
                    issueName: {
                        type: String,
                    },
                    issueDate: {
                        type: String,
                    },
                },
            ],
            inProgress: [
                {
                    issueName: {
                        type: String,
                    },
                    issueDate: {
                        type: String,
                    },
                },
            ],
            completed: [
                {
                    issueName: {
                        type: String,
                    },
                    issueDate: {
                        type: String,
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
});

const UserModel = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

module.exports = UserModel;
```

I've tried to do that but my item hasn't added. (username Kacper exists there is no problem with that).

```
UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { username: 'Kacper' },
    {
        $push: {
            nextUp: [
                {
                    issueName: 'MY NEW ISSUE',
                    issueDate: 'MY ISSUE DATE',
                },
            ],
        },
    },
);
```

Comment: You have to put the full path to `nextUp` rather than just `nextUp`, also you should provide only a single object not an array of object

Comment: See [documentation examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html#examples) of `$push`.